# Open apps on main monitor even when the main monitor reassigned windows 11

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-11

I'm experiencing an issue with a dual-monitor setup where my main display (an LG monitor) does not consistently remain the primary display after it goes into sleep mode. When the LG monitor sleeps and then wakes up, it regains its status as the main display; however, applications like Steam and others open on the secondary monitor (a Dell monitor) instead of returning to the LG monitor.

**Setup Details:**

Main Display: LG monitor (designated as the primary display in Windows settings)
Secondary Display: Dell monitor
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro

**Issue**:

After the LG monitor goes into sleep mode and wakes up, it becomes the primary display again as expected.
However, applications that were open before the LG monitor went to sleep, and new applications launched after waking up, default to opening on the Dell monitor instead of the LG monitor.

**Steps Taken:**

Ensured LG monitor is set as the primary display in the display settings.
Checked power settings to prevent unnecessary sleep modes.

*Questions*:

How can I ensure that after the LG monitor wakes from sleep, applications will default back to opening on it instead of the Dell monitor?

Any advice or solutions to ensure that the primary display maintains its priority for application windows after sleep would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

**solution:**

I found a short solution and i'm still searching for a better one.
i have this bat file that i run to reload the monitors using multiMonitorTool file:
@echo off

*C:\path\to\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 2>**(number of the target monitor)***

*C:\path\to\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 2>**(number of the target monitor)***

> i found pretty slow and inconvenient